# How to redraw vector tiles without cleaning cache?

Tags: leaflet, vector-tiles

I have vector tiles layer, and i want to redraw this layer, but i want to save my cached data. 
So i can't use leaflet function `redraw()` because this is deleting me my cache.

Is there any function to do this? I only want do draw this tiles again without any calculations, because they are made earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found an answer. It's probably good.
if our vector tiles layer is called tileLayer, then we can simple write this:

```
tileLayer._reset();
tileLayer._update();
```